# Changing 'current' class on navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

first post btw.

So I'm creating a portfolio page. It's per now just a single page, with multiple sections as you scroll down. I Have a navigation bar which can be toggled, and when you click on one of the "sections" you get scrolled down to it.

However, when someone presses say the "Projects" link, what javascript code could I use to make it so that when the page gets to that section, it changes the color style in the navigation bar? I have a styles class named current which has the style I want to apply when that section is in focus or clicked.

I hope the question was understandable. Thank you in advance. (P.S. I'm a beginner)

## EDIT

This is my HTML code for the nav-bar, also the Javascript which opens and closes it, I'm not sure where to go next when it comes to having it change class on a certain section of the page.

HTML nav code:

```
<header>
  <div class="menu-btn noSelect">
    <div class="btn-line"></div>
    <div class="btn-line"></div>
    <div class="btn-line"></div>
  </div>

  <nav class="menu noSelect">
    <div class="menu-branding"></div>
    <ul class="menu-nav">
      <li class="nav-item current">
        <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#work" class="nav-link">My Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Select DOM Items
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
const menuNav = document.querySelector(".menu-nav");
const menuBranding = document.querySelector(".menu-branding");
const navItem = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");

// Set Initial state of the menu
let showMenu = false;

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu() {
  // Opens the navigation bar
  if (!showMenu) { 
    menuBtn.classList.add("close");
    menu.classList.add("show");
    menuNav.classList.add("show");
    menuBranding.classList.add("show");
    navItem.forEach(item => item.classList.add("show"));

    // Set Menu state to true
    showMenu = true;
  }
  // Closes the navigation bar 
  else { 
    menuBtn.classList.remove("close");
    menu.classList.remove("show");
    menuNav.classList.remove("show");
    menuBranding.classList.remove("show");
    navItem.forEach(item => item.classList.remove("show"));

    // Set Menu state to false 
    showMenu = false;
  }
}
```

Kind regards,
Tarald

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to better help you, would you please update your question to contain all relevant code or anything you've tried in a [minimal, complete & verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Additionally, providing screenshots of the problem and details of what you’ve tried, make it much more likely that you’ll get a useful answer. 

For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: Do you use any CSS framework?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir , I'm using SCSS and vanilla CSS. Nothing else.

Comment: You could use Boostrsp's **[Scroll Spy](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp)**. It sis easy to use and reliable.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir that would be an option, but adding Bootstrap this late into the project completely ruins the style I'm afraid. So that's a no-go. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't too tricky, I'm pretty sure it's a question that's been asked and answered before at some point, but let me try and point you in the right direction.

You've not provided any code, but I'm going to assume you've got a pretty standard nav bar which is probably a `ul` and it contains a few items which will be `li` elements.  It probably looks like this:

```
<ul class="navigation">
  <li class="navigation__item">Nav item</li>
  <li class="navigation__item">Nav item</li>
  <li class="navigation__item">Nav item</li>
  <li class="navigation__item">Nav item</li>
</ul>
```

And, let's say you've sprinkled some quick and basic styling on it so that it outputs the items horizontally, shows a pointer icon when hovering, and has a hover state so that the individual nav items change background colour on hover.  You also mention that you've got a `current` class ready to go, so I've thrown that in there as well:

```
.navigation {
  background: #ccc;
}
.navigation__item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navigation__item:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
.navigation__item.current {
  background: #eee;
}
```

You seem to be asking about how to use JS to apply the 'current' class to the nav items whenever they are clicked on.  I'd set up event listeners to watch the items, and then when one is clicked on trigger some script which applies the `current` class, and also removes any existing `current` classes from the other items.  That might look a bit like this:

```
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__item');

for (let i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
  navItems[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    Array.from(navItems, navItem => navItem.classList.remove('current'));
    navItems[i].classList.add('current');
  });
}
```

[You can see all of this working together](https://jsbin.com/pinicihepo/edit?html,css,js,output) if it makes life easier.  Hopefully this should help get your own version implemented.

Comment: Thank you, as this was very informative and it did most of what I want. I added it to my own with some tweaks, and when I click each nav item, it works like a charm.

I was also wondering how I can manipulate the DOM so that the current class is changed when the particular section on the page is in view, or when it hits a certain point on the page. For example on this page: https://pierre.io/ - you see the border-bottom change when you hit that section on the page by scrolling aswell.

Any tips? Hope that was understandable.